# Shudder vibration under acceleration in front-wheel-drive, but completely fine when rolling?

Tags: honda, vibration, crv, cv-joint, front-wheel-drive

I have a 2013 Honda CRV front-wheel drive. It has a nasty shuddering vibration when driving on the freeway. This vibration only occurs under acceleration, it goes away when off the gas and just rolling, regardless of speed. We have rotated the wheels, and this hasn't helped. Alignment seems fine and car is great when rolling. There is no mechanical noise associated with it, just a wobbling vibration that gets very nasty. Uncomfortable to drive, wobbles the entire vehicle. It's like day and night, the vehicle wobble only happens under acceleration, but goes away instantly when off the gas.
A mechanic has advised it might be a CV joint. Ive had the wheels off and inspected and the boots look fine and the CV shaft looks ok externally. Is there any way to tell if I have a bad CV joint? Any other recommendations to test/try. Have a lift and tools and looking at replacing both CV joints but wanted some advice first.

Comment: Besides the CV joints, better check the motor mounts too.

Answer (score 0):

It's shudder due to worn automatic transmission fluid (ATF).  See this [forum discussion](https://www.crvownersclub.com/threads/vibration-when-accelerating.188669/).  You don't mention the vehicle's miles or last transmission service.  I would highly recommend changing the transmission fluid using Lube Gard [Complete Full Synthetic](https://www.lubegard.com/products/atf/).  If you see improvement, change the fluid again in a month.  I used it my Mercedes E350 and it eliminated a slippage.  There's nothing like it.

If you'd like to check the CV joints, drive the car in a tight circle and begin to accelerate.  Drive in the tightest circle a few times, in both directions.  Usually, you will hear a clicking sound if the joints are bad.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's a manual transmission, not auto. The CV joints are not making any noise at all. I will test the tight circle thing. MTA said maybe engine mounts, I will take a look at these.